# POS system SQL query for cart display C#

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am developing a POS system for a stationary. I am currently stuck in the sales page. I want to add to data grid view a product when user inputs barcode, quantity, discount and client id and this is the error I am getting:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'transaction'

```cs
string query;
string query2;
using (SqlConnection sqlcon2 = new SqlConnection(cons))
{
    query = "insert into dbo.transaction set (qte,remise,idclt) values ('" + textBox4.Text + "','" + comboBox1.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "')";
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlcon2);
}

using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(cons))
{
    sqlcon.Open();
                
    query2 = "select produit.idprod, produit.nom_produit, transaction.qte, transaction.remise, transaction.idclt, transaction.qte*produit.prixV as Total from [dbo].[produit] join [dbo].[transaction]  on produit.idprod=transaction.idprod join [dbo].[clients] clt on clt.idclt=transaction.idclt where produit.idprod= '" + textBox4.Text+"' and transaction.qte='"+textBox5.Text+"'";
    SqlDataAdapter sda2 = new SqlDataAdapter(query2, sqlcon);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda2.Fill(dt);
    dgv.DataSource = dt;
}
```

**Database Schema:**

[image: The database's schema]

**Form Design:**

[image: The form's design]

Comment: Did the answer below help you resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.

It's highly likely that the problem in your code is the table's name being `transaction`, a keyword in the RDBMS you are using (as evidenced by the exception's message). Try to change it to something else.

In addition, your snippet is vulnerable to an [SQL injection attack](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection). Unless your project is well into development, you should consider using an ORM framework like [Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/).

Comment: Table name is `transaction` not `transactions` and problem can be solved with the use of square brackets e.g. `[transaction]` - although renaming is a better option.